# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, typeerror

I am getting this error when I run my code on the live server but not when I run it on localhost `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function`

The full error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function (anonymous
>   function) @ UploadPOD.aspx?id=uploadOutturn:69 n @
>   jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 o.fireWith @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
>   e.extend.ready @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 c.addEventListener.B @
>   jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2

Is there something wrong with jQuery?

```
<link href="../CSS/DSStyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link href="JS/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="../JS/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And why isn't this error coming up on my localhost?

Comment: jQuery UI isn't loading

Comment: href="JS" and href="../JS" sure both paths are correct?

Comment: Maybe you dind't upload jQuery UI.

Comment: @adeneo how do I fix this?

Comment: @AlexK. yes the paths are correct

Comment: @jcubic what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `jquery-ui` too along with `jquery`

```
<link href="../CSS/DSStyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link href="JS/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="../JS/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The error is that it cant find the function `$().dialog` as it is not present in `jquery`. It is a function of `jquery-ui.js`

Comment: I get the error `object reference not set to an instance of an object` when I add `jquery-ui`

Comment: Did you add your scripts in the same order as given here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you jquery source path isn't correct, so please check the script path first or for testing purpose you can use CDN link.